# Unable to drag and drop a text box in flowlayoutcontainer in gxt

Tags: java, gwt, drag-and-drop, gxt

I want to drag a text box from vertical layout container and drop it in a flow layout container. On drop, it should appear as a Rich Text Area. Please find the code below. I tried to debug the code and it is getting entered only inside dragging. Debugging is not coming inside droptarget. Can you please help me?

```
final TextButton textButton = new TextButton();
    textButton.setText("Text Box");
    DragSource source = new DragSource(textButton) {
        @Override
        protected void onDragStart(DndDragStartEvent event) {
          super.onDragStart(event);
        }
      };

      DropTarget  dropTarget = new DropTarget(flowLayoutContainer);
      dropTarget.setOperation(Operation.COPY);
      dropTarget.addDropHandler(new DndDropHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onDrop(DndDropEvent event) {
                final RichTextArea textBox1 = new RichTextArea();
                flowLayoutContainer.add(textBox1);
            }
        });
```

[image]